# How can I convert a hex ASCII string to a signed integer

Tags: python, binary

Input = 'FFFF'                  # 4 ASCII F's

desired result ... -1 as an integer

code tried:

```
hexstring = 'FFFF'
result = (int(hexstring,16))
print result #65535
```

Result: 65535

Nothing that I have tried seems to recognized that a 'FFFF' is a representation of a negative number.

Comment: something like (I don't know the syntax) `if(value > 0x7FFF) value -= 0x10000`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python converts FFFF at 'face value', to decimal 65535

```
input = 'FFFF'
val = int(input,16) # is 65535
```

You want it interpreted as a 16-bit signed number.
The code below will take the lower 16 bits of any number, and 'sign-extend', i.e. interpret
as a 16-bit signed value and deliver the corresponding integer

```
val16 = ((val+0x8000)&0xFFFF) - 0x8000
```

This is easily generalized

```
def sxtn( x, bits ):
     h= 1<<(bits-1)
     m = (1<<bits)-1
     return ((x+h) & m)-h
```

Comment: And yes, 'if val >= 0x8000: val -= 0x10000' also works fine in the case when the input is known to be 0 .. 0xFFFF (from Jan Dvorak).

Answer (score 2):

In a language like C, 'FFFF' can be interpreted as either a signed (-1) or unsigned (65535) value. You can use Python's struct module to force the interpretation that you're wanting.

Note that there may be endianness issues that the code below makes no attempt to deal with, and it doesn't handle data that's more than 16-bits long, so you'll need to adapt if either of those cases are in effect for you.

```
import struct

input = 'FFFF'

# first, convert to an integer. Python's going to treat it as an unsigned value.
unsignedVal = int(input, 16)
assert(65535 == unsignedVal)
# pack that value into a format that the struct module can work with, as an 
# unsigned short integer
packed = struct.pack('H', unsignedVal)
assert('\xff\xff' == packed)

# ..then UNpack it as a signed short integer
signedVal = struct.unpack('h', packed)[0]
assert(-1 == signedVal)
```

Comment: The endianness is not an issue here, since the h and H operations will always have the same endianness.

Comment: Ah, true. +1 to your answer.